# Let $G$ a finite group and $p$ a prime. If $P$ is the unique p-Sylow of $G$ and $f: G \to G$ is an homomorphism, then $f(P) < P$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ a finite group and $p$ a prime. If $P$ is the unique p-Sylow of $G$ and $f: G \to G$ is an homomorphism, then $f(P) < P$.

Well, as $P$ is the unique p-Sylow of $G$, $P$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
$f(P)$ is a group of $G$, indeed

$1 \in P$ and $f$ homomorphism implies in $f(1) = 1 \in f(P)$

$x,y \in f(P) \to \exists \alpha, \beta \in P, f(\alpha)=x$ and $f(\beta)=y$. As $\alpha \beta \in P$, we have $xy = f(\alpha)f(\beta) = f (\alpha \beta) \in f(P)$.

$x \in P \to x^{-1} \in P$. If $y = f(x)$, then $y^{-1} = f(x) ^{-1} = f(x^{-1}) \in f(P)$

My problem is showing that $f(P) \subset P$.

Thank you

Comment: $f(P)$is a $p$-group, so it is contained in some Sylow $p$-subgroup, but $P$ is the only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $|G| = p^m d$, $gcd(d,p)=1$. We have that $f(P) \cong P/\ker f \cap P$. Hence $|f(P)| \mid |P|$, so $|f(P)| = p^s$, $1 \le s \le m$ (i.e., $f(P)$ is a $p$-subgroup). By Sylow's second theorem, $f(P) \subset$ in a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.